# Modal Javascript - Required on it

Tags: javascript, html, input, modal-dialog

I got Modal opened when people click on like Submit button. My problem is, Required field dosnt work.
Show "Required field" but my modal got opened.

How i can tell my javascript code to check "required" input before opening the modal please ? Thanks.

There is my javascript :

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="e.g. My TikToken" required>
```

Put this, but dosnt work :

```
var inputName = document.getElementById("fname").value;

btn.onclick = function() {
  if (inputName !== "") {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal" style="display: none">
      <button class="close">X</button>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-content">I am a modal</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <form>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="fname"
        name="firstname"
        placeholder="e.g. My TikToken"
        required
      />
      <input type="submit" id="myBtn" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <script>
      var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
      var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
      var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
      var inputName = document.getElementById("fname").value;

      // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
      btn.addEvenetListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (inputName !== "") {
          modal.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          alert("Input cannot be blank.");
        }
      });

      // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
      span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      };

      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
      window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`required` html attribute works on form submissions.  Your modal does not know or care what field is required.  You need to manually check the fields to see if their value is empty or if it satisfies whatever conditions you impose, only then open the modal.

I am just guessing your HTML, so you can fill in the blanks with your css and your modal style.  But the basic framework is there.

Comment: Hello.

I cant do it mate..

```
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
var inputName = document.getElementById("fname").value;

btn.onclick = function() {
  if (inputName !== "") {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="e.g. My TikToken" required>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? which part is not working?

Comment: that work ! But its not opening my modal and redirect me to index.html?fname=test because of from submit button.. I try to google it but i can't fix the problem ..

Comment: ur code didnt work too : "/qsd.html?firstname=test"

Comment: I am not sure what your question is.  About your previous comment, if you ass `e.preventDefault()` you should not be redirected from your page on submit.